# How to convert Row values into column which is containing string values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my Table name TABLE1

```
ID |    ColumnName        |  ColumnValue
----------------------------------- 
48 |    VehicleNo         |  ABC-0134
48 |    In-Time           |  10:00
48 |    Out-Time          |  11:00
```

And I want result as bellow:

```
ID  | VehicleNo  | In-Time |  Out-Time
```

---

```
48  | ABC-0134   | 10:00   |  11:00
```

Please help me to get desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is by using `Pivot` .

```
SELECT [ID], [VehicleNo],
       [In-Time],
       [Out-Time]
FROM   (SELECT id,
               ColumnName,
               ColumnValue
        FROM   tablename) a
       PIVOT (Max(columnvalue)
             FOR coulnname IN([VehicleNo],
                              [In-Time],
                              [Out-Time])) piv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `pivot`, conditional aggregation, or joins.  Here is one method:

```
select max(case when ColumnName = 'VehicleNo' then ColumnValue end) as VehicleNo,
       max(case when ColumnName = 'In-Time' then ColumnValue end) as InTime,
       max(case when ColumnName = 'Out-Time' then ColumnValue end) as OutTime
from table1
group by id;
```